# Get the value of two dynamic dropdown list

Tags: php, html

So I have this code that I use to generate to generate two dynamic drop down list:

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1><center>Equipe</center></h1>    

        <FORM METHOD="POST">
            <table>
                <thead> <!-- En-tête du tableau -->
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <select name="ListeEquipe1" id="ListeEquipe1"><br/>
                                <option value="" slected="selected"></option>
                                <?php
                                 $resultat = $bdd->query('SELECT distinct Equipe1 FROM equipe Order by Equipe1 ASC') or die (print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
                                    while ($donnees = $resultat->fetch())
                                    {
                                        echo '<option value="' . $donnees['Equipe1'] . '">' . $donnees['Equipe1'] .  '</option>';
                                    }
                                    $resultat->closeCursor();?>
                            </select>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <select name="ListeEquipe2" id="ListeEquipe2"><br/> 
                                <option value="" slected="selected"></option>
                                <?php
                                 $resultat = $bdd->query('SELECT distinct Equipe2 FROM equipe Order by Equipe2 ASC') or die (print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));;
                                    while ($donnees = $resultat->fetch())
                                    {
                                        echo '<option value="' . $donnees['Equipe2'] . '">' . $donnees['Equipe2'] .  '</option>';
                                    }
                                    $resultat->closeCursor();?>
                            </select>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>%Equipe 1</th>
                        <th>%Equipe 2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

And then I need to get the selected values of the two list and then display values that are in the same database when I click, I'm using that for the moment, the two request must get the two selected values :

```
<tbody>
                    <tr><!-- Corps du tableau -->
                    <?php
                            $resultat = $bdd->query('SELECT PEquipe1 FROM equipe Where Equipe1 LIKE "test1e1"') or die (print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
                                    while ($donnees = $resultat->fetch())
                                    {
                                        ?><td><?php echo $donnees['PEquipe1'];?></td><?php
                                    }
                                    $resultat->closeCursor();?>
                    <?php
                            $resultat = $bdd->query('SELECT  PEquipe2 FROM equipe Where Equipe2 Like "test1e2"') or die (print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
                                    while ($donnees = $resultat->fetch())
                                        {
                                            ?><td><?php echo $donnees['PEquipe2'];?></td><?php
                                        }
                                            $resultat->closeCursor();?>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <th>Equipe 1</th>
                        <th>Equipe 2</th>                        
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
            </table>
            <div>
            <INPUT src="94.jpg" class="btns" onclick="ListeEquipe1;" type="submit" value="Calcul" href=""/>
        </div>
        </FORM>
```

And I need to use only html and PHP.
Is that possible ? 
Because when I tried using the Id I had an Undefined Index.

Comment: you dont close the form and there is no submit button, you dont use `$_POST['ListeEquipe1;]` anywhere, this is a bit of a mess currently

Comment: Yeah sorry, I divided my code in Two section but it's working, the form is closed, It's just that I need a method to do this thing because when I used the $_Post['ListeEquipe1;'] it didn't worked.

Comment: its `$_POST` not `$_Post`

Comment: That's I meant don't worry I get it